# Google Cast SDK - getting a network timeout a few seconds after opening a session

Tags: android, google-cast

This is my `openSession` method, based on the sample's:

```
    Log.d("asdf", "Beginning session with context: " + mCastContext);
    Log.d("asdf", "The session to begin: " + mSession);
    mSession.setListener(new com.google.cast.ApplicationSession.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onSessionStarted(ApplicationMetadata appMetadata) {
            Log.d("asdf", "Getting channel after session start");
            ApplicationChannel channel = mSession.getChannel();
            if (channel == null) {
                Log.e("asdf", "channel = null");
                return;
            }
            Log.d("asdf", "Creating and attaching Message Stream");
            mMessageStream = new MediaProtocolMessageStream();
            channel.attachMessageStream(mMessageStream);

            if (mMessageStream.getPlayerState() == null) {
                if (mMedia != null) {
                    loadMedia(mMedia);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("asdf", "Found player already running");
//              updateStatus(); TODO
            }
        }
```

It works fine, and I can push content to Leapcast (emulator) in a short window of time, usually about 6 seconds.

After that 6 seconds, however, I get this:

```
Log: onEnded failed to connect channel: network I/O timeout
```

Called from `onSessionEnded`.

What exactly is ending my session? Is it just an issue with Leapcast? Do I need to do some sort of keep-alive?

Comment: We haven't evaluated the Leapcast emulator, we strongly recommend that you use a real device that has been whitelisted.

Comment: Now I wish I had a TV :(
But it's a good possibility it's an emulator problem? Any chance of Google releasing an official emulator soon?

Comment: You don't need a real TV. Any monitor with HDMI input (it's very common nowadays) can be plugged in the chromecast.

Comment: Having the same issue with Leapcast. Not quite sure what's going on